# is it possible to get notification from browser when page is loaded completely?

Tags: ios, time, notifications, load, html

if I want to design an iPhone app to do this monitoring, is it possible? such as open the app and input web address, the app can call safari's function to request and render the webpage, so that i can monitor the page load event in the app. How can I achieve that? 
or

create an app that monitors the time taken to load a web page by any browser on iPhone. let suppose i have button in my app on clicking the button my app will start monitoring the other apps, now if i start safari(or any browser) and try to open web page, than the time taken to load web page must be calculated by my app. is it possible to do??

Comment: Checkout [UIWebView Class referance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Specially delegate methods.

Comment: You have to use UIWebView. I think you will not have access to browser after opening URL.

Comment: thanks @mahacs and @N J Gadhiya but i don't want to use UIWebView. i want to monitor another apps running in background. can we get any notification when i open browser or launch any app.u might have used battery doctor app which monitors battery use of all apps, in same way i want to monitor the websites load time on browsers.

Comment: You can't monitor any other installed apps at all. Read about IOS sandboxing.